# AngularJS: GET request sent after POST request returned with 302 for login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, spring-security, httprequest, http-redirect

I am implementing a Login page for authentication. AngularJS sends a post request to server with user credentials.

```
//service.js
authApp.factory("loginFactory", function ($http) {
    return{
        login: function(username, password) {
            var data = {username: username, password: password};
            serialize = function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                  str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
              return str.join("&");
            }

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
                data: serialize(data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            });  
        }
    }   
});
```

My controller below handles success and failure. For debugging purpose, I only print out response instead of redirecting.

```
authApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginFactory', function($scope, $location, loginFactory){
    $scope.authenticate = function() {
        loginFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

When I run it, the POST request would return 302 with no response. And a GET request will start right after. If the password is correct, it will be redirected to "http://localhost:8080/". If password is wrong, it will be redirected to "http://localhost:8080/login?error. Since I don't have handlers for either path, it will return 401 error. The Angular controller will capture the response from GET requests as if it is the response from the Post request.

At the back end, the authentication done by Spring Security. Here is the security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
                //.loginPage("/login");
    }
```

Where does the GET request come from? Why does the original post request trigger a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET request is due to the 302 being returned by server. In conventional form login, spring will:

1. Handle POST request for login
2. Redirect to success page (`/`) in case of success and error ('/login?error`)

Browser transparently handles the redirect.

In case you want to change the default behaviour of spring, I would suggest you to refer to the [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/). The tutorial uses basic authentication rather than form login. However, if you require form login you will have to implement custom authentication success and failure handlers. Something like the following:

Security Config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/error").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin()
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler).and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler);
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler);

}
```

`CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` to return status code 401 instead of redirection to failure handler url.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    }

}
```

`AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler` to return status 200 instead of redirection to logout success url

```
@Component
public class AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
        implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

`CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` to return 401 instead of redirection to login page

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    }

}
```

`CustomAccessDeniedHandler` to return 401 instead of redirection to access denied page.

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    }

}
```

I hope this helps.